# pgfplots: Rescaling axis using factor, with nice tick labels/locations

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to normalize the axis of a pgfplots graph by certain values, something like `2000` for the y-axis and `19099` for the x-axis. The y-axis looks nice as expected, but the x-axis being scaled by a not nice number, produces tick labels that are something like `0.52`, `1.05`, `1.57`, etc. rather than `0.5`, `1`, `1.5` etc.

Is there a way to scale the axis but still place the ticks at nice locations automatically?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0,xmax = 70000,
        ymin = 0,ymax = 5000,
        scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{(#1)/(19099)}},
        scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{(#1)/(2000)}},
      ]
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**UPDATE**

Trying @Jake approach, gives me errors when I plot a function within my axis, see following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0,xmax = 70000,
        ymin = 0,ymax = 5000,
        domain=0:70000,
        x coord trafo/.code={
          \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
          \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(19099)}
          \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
        y coord trafo/.code={
          \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
          \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(2000)}
          \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
%        scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{(#1)/(19099)}},
%        scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{(#1)/(2000)}},
        ]
        \addplot {2000+0.001*(x/60)^2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

This produces errors, such as: ``! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scaled x ticks` key only acts after the tick positions have already been determined, so they're not the way to go here. Instead, you should transform your coordinate system using `x coord trafo/.code` and `y coord trafo/.code`.

Note that for values as large as yours, you'll need to switch on the `fpu` library in the `.code`. When using `xmin`, `xmax`, etc., the `fpu` library needs to be deactivated after the calculation, but when plotting mathematical expressions, the library may not be deactivated. This is a bit cumbersome: You'll have to `\pgflibraryfpuifactive` to decide whether we're in a context where the libary should be switched on and off, or left as it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=70000,
      ymin=0, ymax=5000,
        domain=0:70000,
        x coord trafo/.code={
            \pgflibraryfpuifactive{
                \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(19099)}
            }{
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
                \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(19099)}
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
            }
        },
        y coord trafo/.code={
            \pgflibraryfpuifactive{
                \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(2000)}
            }{
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
                \pgfmathparse{(#1)/(2000)}
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
            }
        },
        ]
        \addplot {2000+0.001*(x/60)^2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: this works quite nicely for coordinate plots. If I add a function to plot, it gives me errors, see update to original post.

Comment: @Markus: I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jake should `x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/19099}}` be faster? Shouldn't it? (the same for y axis). You have to adapt the plot range.

Comment: @Luigi: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Just using that `x filter` will not work if you want to set `xmin` and `xmax` manually.

Comment: @Jake, set `xmin=0, xmax=3.67` and that's all.

Comment: @Luigi: Ah, sorry, I missed that you're using `x filter` instead of `coord trafo`. I thought about that, but I would prefer specifying the `xmin` and `xmax` in the data range, not the scaled range. You should probably add your approach as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Easier but dirtier than Jake's solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=3.67,
  ymin=0, ymax=5000,
  domain=0:70000,
  x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/19099}},
  scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/2000}}
  ]
\addplot {2000+0.001*(x/60)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe dirtier, but still works! I will check if performance here is any different. Especially for lots of curves with lots of samples this might get cumbersome I guess. Thanks!